# Why doesn't gcc optimize matching throw and catch?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Consider this snippet:

```cpp
static inline void g() {
    throw 10;
}

int f() {
    try {
        g();
    } catch (const int &x) {
        return x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[As you can see from the Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3hEssKeGe), GCC is able to inline the call to `g`, but still goes through the whole process of throwing and catching the expression, calling the runtime library. Is there any reason why GCC couldn't just compile `f` to `mov eax, 10; ret`? The same happens with clang, with little differences.

An optimization like this would seem when the compiler can inline the throwing site inside the catching site, which perhaps would happen frequently if you call some throwing STL method and catch just outside the call. I guess that avoiding going through the runtime could be a significant improvement in hot loops.

Comment: If you have exceptions that are actually thrown in hot loops, you should redesign. Exeptions are meant to be exceptional.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53294 and many others. As with most similar questions, the answer is mostly "because nobody has made the effort to implement it". There is also this self-fulfilling loop where people say exceptions are slow and souldn't be used where perf matters, which decreases the motivation for compilers to optimize, which reinforces this impression that exceptions shouldn't be used where perf matters :-(

Comment: It’s always weird to hear the nostrum about how C++ exceptions are *meant* to be slow and awful, when comparing to languages where they’re not.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for the link. So, from those bugs it seems that there is not reason in the specs that prohibit this optimization. If you want to write your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Mat If exceptions turn out to be fast anyway, why should I avoid them? Why can't I consider them a zero-cost abstraction as many others?